# Are variables objects in Scala?

Tags: scala

Since Scala is a pure object oriented language, how are variables then objects themselves? I can see the literal value being an object itself in Scala, but not sure about the variables.

Comment: What do you mean with the variable? So a variable store an object, but the concept of variable is not an object.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Variables are *not* objects in Scala. This is not unique to Scala, it is true for *all* mainstream programming languages, even languages like Haskell or Smalltalk, and it is in fact true for *almost all* programming languages in general.

Every *value* is an object in Scala, but variables are *not* values, and thus are not objects. There are other things which are not values, most notably *types*. Types, classes, traits, and also methods.

`object`s sometimes *look* like they are both values and types, but actually, they are not. If you define an `object Foo`, then `Foo` is a value, but the type is the singleton type `Foo.type`, not `Foo` itself. For companion modules, you indeed have both a type named `Foo`, and a value named `Foo`, but those are different things. (Values and types can have the same name precisely *because* they are strictly separate, and thus there is never any possible confusion which of the two you are talking about.)

*Literal types* also *look* like you are using values as types, but actually, that is simply syntactic sugar. The literal type `42` is actually just syntactic sugar for the singleton type `42.type`. Again, this works because values and types are two separate universes, and so there is never any context where it is unclear whether we are talking about the value or the literal type.

Another thing that isn't an object is the language syntax.

The only two languages I know about where variables are indeed objects that you can talk about and manipulate, are [Ioke](https://ioke.org/) and [Seph](https://seph-lang.org/).

Comment: "[...] but variables are not values, and thus are not objects." - this implication is not that obvious for me